# How can I import file csv? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, import, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    {!! Form::label('import', 'Import File:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('import_file', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    <a href="{!! route('customers.index') !!}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

My controller is like this :

```
if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
    dd('test');
    $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();
    if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
        ...
    }
}
```

I upload file csv. Then I save it

But, it does not run dd('test'). Whereas I have uploaded it

How can I solve t?

Comment: Can you post the entire form and all code from your controller method? Maybe something is blocking it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `'files' => true` inside the array of `Form::open`

Example:  `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true]) !!}`